# SQL Server Setup Error in Visual studio 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssdt-bi

i have installed sql sever 2012 with SSDT.
When i am using SSDT and creating package.It gives error:
Microsoft Visual Studio is unable to load this document:
To Design Integration Services packages in sql Server Data Tools (SSDT),SSDT Has to be installed by one of these edition of sql server 2012:Standard,Enterprise,Developer,or Evaluation.

I am using Sql server 2012 Enterprise Edition.
SSDT also installed on my machine.

I dont know y rhis error is occured???.
Please anybody help me

Answer (score 0):

**Refer all the discussion in following link**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/6dce2f25-2f73-4f69-8d37-06483ada79da/

**As well go through this step by step approach:**

http://learnsqlwithbru.com/2011/12/12/getting-started-with-ssdt-sql-server-data-tools/

Hope its helpful.